# Unable to create a closure for a function inside of object instance to send to another object

Tags: javascript, closures

I have this :

```
objectA .....

objectB = function (){
    value:1,
    do_things: function (param1, param2, option) {bla bla},
    connect : function  (dest){
        My_objectA.set_external_do_thing  = function  ?????????
    }
}
```

Then I have :

```
MY_objectA = new objetA();
MY_objectB = new objetB(); 
MY_objectB.connect(My_objectA);
```

I'd like to write the right code to send a `do_things` function to ObjectA and then call it from there. `do_things` uses local variables `param1` and `param2`. I need to set them but I can't.

By now I have a lot of undefined messages I can't solve.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have the code for `set_external_do_thing` then post it. And `param1` together with `param2` are local to which scope? `objectB` body?

Comment: You're mixing object literal with function syntax. Please provide syntactically valid, or even executable, example code.

Comment: -Elmo : param1,param2 would be variables inr objectB. Option would be set by ObjectA .  >> 'set_external_do_thing' must be as simple as this : set_external_do_thing = function (a_function,params) { my_option= some_value; a_function (params[0],params[1],somevalue);}. I hope now my problem was clearer.   -Bergi: I cant send code because it is too long. I think I have sent the main idea ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bergi right said you made some mistakes, I fix them and tried to implement a sample from what I understand is your doubt... take a look...

Assume that you have two objects:

```
var husband = {
    spentFactor: 1,
    buyThings: function () {
      console.log('bla bla');
    },
    buyOtherThings: function (param1) {
      console.log("Final Cost: " + (param1*this.spentFactor));
    }
};

var wife = {
    spentFactor: 10,
    buyThings: function () {
      console.log('bla bla');
    }
};
```

then if you want to use `buyOtherThings()` method from `husband` object, but you know we man have a different spent factor:

```
husband.buyOtherThings(20);
husband.buyOtherThings.apply(wife, [20]);
```

The `apply()` method is the key, every function descend from a Function object and you inherits this by default. This method permit that you change the `this` from a object, so we can reuse a function from a different object.

play around this code [here](http://jsbin.com/yowef/5/edit?js,console)